# Listview item clicks

Tags: android

I have a listview with some items.I want to know the list item click.for example if i click on listview item 1st time a toast message will be a appeared.again same item clicked the toast message will be you clicked the same item second time.

finally i want to know that individual listview item "EVEN" clicks and "ODD" clicks

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
{ public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        if(firstTime) {
            firstTime = false;
            if(count%2==0){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Clicked on Row2nd: " +
                country.getName(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                count=0;
            }
            else{
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Clicked on Row1st: " +
                country.getName(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                count=0;
            }
        }
        else{
            firstTime=true;
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Clicked on Row1111: " +
            country.getName(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            count=count+1;

        }
    }
});
```

Comment: You can add variable(say `clickCount`) to your model that is used in `listview` and increment it with every click

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add an additional ArrayList, that will contain a counter for each of your list view items.

Let say that you have:

```
ArrayList<String> listViewData = getSomeData();
ArrayList<Integer> dataClickCount = new ArrayList<>();
for(String item : listViewData)
{
    dataClickCount.add(0);
}
```

And later in your listener:

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() { public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

   if(dataClickCount.get(posion)%2==0){
       Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Clicked on Row1nd, odd click: " + country.getName(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
       dataClickCount.set(posion,1);
   }
   else{
       Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Clicked on Row2st, even click: " + country.getName(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        dataClickCount.set(posion,0);
   }


}});
```

Comment: Thank you @regev avraham